# Validating in the client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client-side

I use four asp.net text boxes to capture data. I need to allow data to entered if at least one  textbox is populated. I want to do this in client side, using javascript. I can do this server side. I don't wanna send a request to server for only this. I am not good at javascript.

Comment: You've asked a total of 10 questions and have not even so much as marked one of them as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validate your form onsubmit event.

Create a function that validate your fields and then return a boolean. If result is false the form will not be sand.

Example for validate funcition, this will return true only if your field text value has more then 10 chars.

```
function validate() {
    return document.form.fieldId.value.length > 10;
}
```

Try to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com), its simpler to do this task like:

```
function validate() {
    return $("#fieldId").val().length > 10;
}
```

In the HTML form tag:

```
<form onSubmit="validate()">...</form>
```

You can customize the code to do other things, but this is the main idea.